# NSTreeController: how do I find the parent of a node?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstreecontroller

I'm looking for a similar method to: `NSOutlineView` `parentForItem:` for NSTreeController.

I need to know the parent of a node in the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nodes in an `NSTreeController` are instances of `NSTreeNode`, and `NSTreeNode` has a *read-only* `parentNode` property - so use that.

The short snippet below gets the parent node of the first node in the tree-controller's `selectedNodes` array:

```
let selectedNode = tree.selectedNodes.first! as! NSTreeNode
let parentOfSelectedNode = selectedNode.parentNode!
```